# Strange glyph when moving commandline cursor

Tags: command-line, microsoft-windows

I recently tried vim for the (still in-dev!) Bash for Ubuntu on Windows.

I noticed this odd glyph appearing on the commandline in vim - but only when moving across it. It flashes for one screen update when moving the cursor... Sometimes.

[image: Something that looks like an O appears on the cursor]

Does anyone know of this? From my testing it happens only in vim. (I did try it on bash and nano as well).

If anyone's curious, I'm fairly certain that's an uppercase O - my font has slashed zeroes.

If you need to see more, I uploaded a 105kb webm video of the issue here: https://webmshare.com/play/NELvx, where I also show off the lack of a `.vimrc`

Is it vim? Is it the terminal? Does anyone have any ideas at all?

**Edit**: I know Stackexchange isn't a bug tracker and it most likely is a bug - but if there's some arcane vim setting that causes this I'm interested to know. If not, I'll just write it down as a bug in `conhost.exe`.

Comment: `if there's some arcane vim setting that causes this I'm interested to know`: since the behavior appears with an empty vimrc it doesn't look like an option is causing it. I think you should report it as a bug. (Also a little tip: you can use `vim -u NONE` to start Vim without a vimrc and you don't need to delete the content of your vimrc)

Comment: Ah, no, i LITERALLY do not have a vimrc on this install, haha. This is vim from inside Bash for Ubuntu on Windows (WSL), I usually work in a cygwin enviroment since WSL is still very young (it only recently got more than 16-color support on the insiders build)

Comment: I saw on your gif that you showed that your vimrc was empty and I deduced that you didn't know the `-u` option but I was wrong. And yes this environment is still pretty young so there are good chances that it contains some bugs.

Comment: `:set term=builtin_ansi` changed the displayed `O` to a `[` so it's most likely a bug with the terminal.